# Printer prints the same page endlessly

Tags: printing, cups-lpd

If I give the print command even for a single page to my network printer [HP Leserjet MFP4345](https://www.cnet.com/products/hp-laserjet-m4345-mfp/specs/), the printer prints the same page over and over again until it runs out of page.

Currently I am using Ubuntu 17.10, but i have faced the same problem with earlier version of Ubuntu too without any workable solution.

The "MAKE & MODEL" under Properties of the printer shows "HP LaserJet M4345 MFP Postscript (recommended)".

I have tried "hp-setup -i" and followed the instructions, after completion  the test page again printed repetitively.

The output of "dpkg-query -s cups | grep Status:" is "Status: install ok installed".

Comment: if there is only one icon for this 4345 in your PRINTERS folder, right-click on it; select PROPERTIES; look in the line that says MAKE & MODEL; can you copy what is there; and paste it back here please?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
the info you need is "HP LaserJet M4345 MFP Postscript (recommended)"

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the [edit] button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Comment: I think you have a gutenprint driver working there; if you open a terminal; type `hp-setup` and see if hplip will do a config; if it works, the new icon will say hpcups somewhere in the MAKE & MODEL and that should be better

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please [edit] your post to include the output of `dpkg-query -s cups | grep Status:` Thank you for helping us help you!